# Android PNG bitmap compression not working properly between Note 4 and Nexus 5

Tags: android, bitmap, compression, png

Hi have been using without problems a bitmap conversion to PNG to keep transparency, for some time now. Afterwards sending the stream byte array to other devices.

> bmp.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);

This has been working pretty well so far, until I've started testing with a Nexus5 with android 5.0
and a Note 4 with android 4.4.4.

Up to this point I've used several devices (Note 1, Note 2, S3, S4 among others) and with all of them I receive the PNG properly on the Nexus 5.

When I compress with the Note 4 the Nexus 5 can't seem to decode the byte array

> Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(arr, 0, arr.length);

the image is null.
Other devices that receive that encoded PNG are able to receive and process it with the same code ...
Even if I try to move the PNG to the Nexus I can't open the file on the device, even trying to use the Photos app to see the picture I get the message "Media not found". with PNGs generated on other devices I have no problems at all.

.

I've just tried something else to try to identify the problem... I've used an app to generate a png image (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jun.shop_image_editing_engver&hl=en) and if I generate a PNG on the NOTE 4 I can't open it on the NEXUS, if I generate a PNG on a Note 2 I am able to open it.

Has anybody had any problem like this?

Thanks for the help

EDIT: Just to clarify, other devices can open the image the NOTE 4 generates (the eye below is such an image)

[image: png I compressed with the note4]

Comment: I am getting the same issue using screenshots captured on Android with UIAutomation which ultimately calls `screenshot.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, quality, bos);`. I'm guessing I can't replace the code in UI Automator !

Answer (score 0):

For the image you included in the question, I am seeing an error in the check value of the zlib compressed data.  The producer of the image made a mistake, or the data was corrupted in transit.  Receivers of the image can choose to be more or less lenient on such errors in the data, so it might display in some cases, but not in others.

Comment: Thanks Mark, If that is true, how can I prevent the Note 4 from corrupting an image using the method above? bitmap.compress?
Because if other apps are also corrupting a PNG image (like the app I've linked above) Is there another way of converting a bitmap to a PNG?

Comment: Thanks for the Help Mark, btw how did you check/validated the PNG?

Isn't this a problem that should affect other people/users/apps? isn't libpng a very big overkill? applying this on an android app isn't as simple as adding a jar library that you can use.

Comment: If you link libpng statically, it should only pull in what you need, and no more.  zlib is already there.

Comment: I have my own tool that pulls out the zlib stream from the IDAT chunk(s), and I tested that with zlib.

Answer (score 0):

I've also came across this issue last week. In my case, generated png from note 4 cannot be displayed by asus zenphone 2. But the same png was fine in Xiaomi mi4.

My solution in this case was changing Bitmap.CompressFormat from PNG to WEBP, as WEBP are also capable of creating transparent image.

I know it just 'curing' the symptoms, not the root problem, but at least its enough for me, hope it will enough for you.